# Android MultiThreading with afterTextChanged

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-textwatcher

i started to work with MultiThreading as 
and i wanted to go validate user input so i looked at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929113/android-multithreading-with-textwatcher)

but still from some reason my apps crashed and i can't pinpoint to the problem

RegisterActivity.Java

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
        email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if( !isValidEmail(email))
                    LoginActivity.alertDialog(getApplicationContext(),"test","test");
                    return null;
            }

        }.execute();
    }
```

LoginActivity.java (and yes i know that this function shouldn't be here)

```
  public static   void alertDialog(Context context, CharSequence message, CharSequence type){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setNegativeButton(type, null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:com.example.ofir.bopofinal, PID: 3038
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:351)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:320)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:281)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:258)
                                                                                      at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
                                                                                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
                                                                                      at com.example.ofir.bopofinal.LoginRegister.LoginActivity.alertDialog(LoginActivity.java:53)
                                                                                      at com.example.ofir.bopofinal.LoginRegister.RegisterActivity$3.onPostExecute(RegisterActivity.java:162)
                                                                                      at com.example.ofir.bopofinal.LoginRegister.RegisterActivity$3.onPostExecute(RegisterActivity.java:153)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just do what the Exception tells you:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

EDIT:

You are passing the ApplicationContext to AlertDialog.Builder() constructor. The builder tries to get it's theme from that context and as it's the ApplicationContext and not the Activity, it will take the theme of the application itself, which seems not to be Theme.AppCompat or a descendent.

Without rewriting to much of your code, it should work, if you pass `this` resp. (when calling from within AyncTask) `RegisterActivity.this` to `alertDialog()` as the context to use.

Comment: i did  `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">` in the manifest.xml and im getting the same result, the error is pointing to the  `.show()` in the `alertDialog` function

Comment: I think I found the problem -- see my edited answer.

Comment: Yeah, you should perhaps get rid of the static method, it possible. You could perhaps move the alertDialog method to the RegisterActivity class or some base class for both Activities, if you use it in both of them. Thanks for accepting my answer, btw.

Comment: both activities need a major retouch

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an `Exception` because you are trying to display a `Dialog` from a background `Thread`. You should check if the email is valid inside `onPreExecute()` and if it is not display the dialog then since it runs on the UI `Thread`.

Comment: `onPreExecute()` did not work, and you are right there is why im getting the `Exception` but i dont know how to solve it

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "did not work". Can you be more specific?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: For the AlertDialog class, import the support.v7 version instead of the standard one. When you post a question like this, please include the stactrace from your logcat.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace as part of your question. This stacktrace suggest your `AsyncTask` is not even running.

Comment: i cant post the whole stack trace,it's way to long

Comment: The portion of stacktrace you shared indicates that you are using the wrong `Theme` for the `Activity`.

Comment: add to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Edit : Make sure your activity is extending AppCompatActivity and you are importing android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog instead of the standard one. Then, change the AsyncTask as below :

The doInBackground() method can perform long-running operations but cannot interact with the UI. For that, you should use the onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() methods, like this :

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if( !isValidEmail(email))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isEmailValid) {
            //isEmailValid is the variable received from the doInBackground() method
            if(!isEmailValid)
                LoginActivity.alertDialog(getApplicationContext(),"test","test");
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: getting the same `error java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.` at `com.example.ofir.bopofinal.LoginRegister.LoginActivity.alertDialog(LoginActivity.java:53)`

Comment: @styx - please post the stacktrace of your crash. rhari's answer seems correct, concept-wise. Perhaps the crash's reason is something different.

Comment: @rhari  my app is already extending  AppCompatActivity  and  importing importing android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog